# Flutter bloc not adding event second time

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Hi I am using bloc named `AuthenticationBloc` to store the application auth status.
First of all here is the `main.dart` file.

```
void main() async{
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc(),
    child:  Authentication(),
  );
}
```

`authentication.dart` is like this.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    authenticationBloc = BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context);
    authenticationBloc.add(AppLoaded());
    super.initState();
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
           home:  BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, AuthenticationState state) {
                if (state is AuthenticationInitial) {
                  return SplashScreen();
                }
                if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
                  return new Home();
                }
                if (state is AuthenticationNotAuthenticated) {
                  return MultiBlocProvider(
                    providers: [
                      BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(create: (context) => LoginBloc(authenticationBloc)),
                    ],
                    child:new LoginPage(),
                  );
                }
                if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
                  return SplashScreen();
                }
                return SplashScreen();
              },
        ),

    );
  }
```

Now  `login_bloc.dart` file is.

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  final AuthenticationBloc _authenticationBloc;
  final repository = ApiRepository();

  LoginBloc(AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc)
      : assert(authenticationBloc != null),
        _authenticationBloc = authenticationBloc,
        super(LoginInitial());

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(LoginEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginInWithEmailButtonPressed) {
      yield* _mapLoginWithEmailToState(event);
    }
   
  }

  Stream<LoginState> _mapLoginWithEmailToState(LoginInWithEmailButtonPressed event) async* {
    yield LoginLoading();
    try {
      if (true) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), (){});
        MySharedPreferences.instance.setStringValue('id', '1');
        _authenticationBloc.add(UserLoggedIn(user: User(name:"abc",email:"abc@gmail.com")));
        yield LoginSuccess();
        yield LoginInitial();
      } else {
        yield LoginFailure(error: 'Something very weird just happened');
      }
    } on AuthenticationException catch (e) {
      yield LoginFailure(error: e.message);
    } catch (err) {
      yield LoginFailure(error: err.message ?? 'An unknown error occured');
    }
  }

  }

}
```

In login screen page when i log in then it successfully change the `authentication-bloc` state and navigated to `home`.
In home when i do like this
 `_authenticationBloc.add(UserLoggedOut());` the it successfully log out.
But after that when i click login it dispatch the event but the line
 `_authenticationBloc.add(UserLoggedIn(user: User(name:"abc",email:"abc@gmail.com")));` in `login-bloc` not working and so its not going to home.

Kindly help me why it is not dispatching the event to the `bloc`.
I am stucked at this point.

Thanks in advance.